# PyTorch Gradient not Working after adding to("cuda:0")

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, gradient

I'm going to give a context-free set of code.  The code works before adding "to(device)".

```
def get_input_layer(word_idx) :
x = torch.zeros(vocabulary_size).float().to(device)
x[word_idx] = 1.0
return x

embedding_dims = 5
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
W1 = Variable(torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size).float(), requires_grad=True).to(device)
W2 = Variable(torch.randn(vocabulary_size, embedding_dims).float(), requires_grad=True).to(device)
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.001

x = Variable(get_input_layer(data)).float().to(device)
y_true = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([target])).long()).to(device)
z1 = torch.matmul(W1, x).to(device)
z2 = torch.matmul(W2, z1).to(device)

log_softmax = F.log_softmax(z2, dim=0).to(device)

loss = F.nll_loss(log_softmax.view(1,-1), y_true).to(device)
loss_val += loss.data
loss.backward().to(device)

## Optimize values. This is done by hand rather than using the optimizer function
W1.data -= learning_rate * W1.grad.data
W2.data -= learning_rate * W2.grad.data
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Which triggers specifically on the line

```
W1.data -= learning_rate * W1.grad.data
```

Checking, this is confirmed because W1.grad is None for some reason.

And this loops after clearing the gradients. This works just fine if I remove all of the .to(device).  What is it that I'm doing wrong in trying to run this on my GPU?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `.to` returns a new, non-leaf tensor. You should set `requires_grad` after transferring to the desired device. Also, the `Variable` interface has been deprecated for a long time, since before pytorch 1.0. It doesn't do anything (except in this case act as an overly complicated way to set `requires_grad`).

Consider

```
W1 = Variable(torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size).float(), requires_grad=True).to(device)
```

The problem here is that there are two different tensors. Breaking it down we could rewrite what you're doing as

```
W1a = Variable(torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size).float(), requires_grad=True)
W1 = W1a.to(device)
```

Observe that `W1a` requires a gradient but `W1` is derived from `W1a` so it isn't considered a leaf tensor, therefore the `.grad` attribute of `W1a` will be updated but `W1` won't be. In your code you no longer have a direct reference to `W1a` so you won't have access the gradients.

Instead you can do

```
W1 = torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size).float().to(device)
W1.required_grad_(True)
```

which will properly set `W1` to be a leaf tensor **after** being transfered to a different device.

---

Note that for your specific case we could also just make use of the `device`, `dtype`, and `requires_grad` arguments for `torch.randn` and simply do

```
W1 = torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size, dtype=torch.float, device=device, requires_grad=True)
```

Most pytorch functions which initialize new tensors support these three arguments which can help avoid the issues you've encountered.

---

To respond to OP's additional question in the comments:

> Is there a good spot I would've come across this in the documentation?

AFAIK the documentation doesn't specifically address this issue. It's kind of a combination between how variables in python work and how autograd mechanics work in pytorch.

Assuming you have a good understand of variables in python then you can reach the conclusions of this answer yourself by first reading [`Tensor.is_leaf`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.is_leaf), in particular

> they will be leaf Tensors if they were created by the user. **This means that they are not the result of an operation** and so `grad_fn` is None.

And furthermore the documentation for [`Tensor.to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) which states

> If the `self` Tensor already has the correct `torch.dtype` and `torch.device`, then `self` is returned. **Otherwise, the returned tensor is a copy of `self`** with the desired `torch.dtype` and `torch.device`.

Since `Tensor.to` returns a copy, and a copy is an operation, then it should be clear from the documentation that the `W1` tensor in the original code is not a leaf tensor.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a good spot I would've come across this in the documentation? I looked but I don't think I found anything this clear. Perhaps I wasn't looking in the right place. Appreciate the anwer.

Comment: @Jibril I added an additional discussion addressing your question.